# Which are the bare minimum source files that I should upload to a CodePlex project?

Tags: c#, stylecop, codeplex

I'm looking to revamp an old open source project I've started a couple of months ago. I'm a tidiness fanatic, I really try hard to "[code like a girl](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2006/03/code_like_a_gir.html)" whenever I can. That's why I've been policing my code with StyleCop, which makes me really happy. Now for some reason I've got the feeling that I've uploaded a pile of junk back then with the first commit, so this time I just want to upload only the actual required files, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With it being an open source project, I would say all source files, and at minimum your csproj and .sln files.  You could avoid checking in the .suo files as those are just your IDE options.